# How to make same order of choices in selectizeInput while clicking or typing?

Tags: r, shiny, selectize.js

I made a vector of choices. When I click on selectizeInput, I get choices in the same order as in my vector, but when I start typing in selectizeInput, the order of my choices is not the same as in my vector.

This is example of shiny app.

```
library(shiny)

choices <- c("First choice", "Second choice", "Choice third", "Fourth choice", "Choice fifth")

ui <- fluidPage(

    selectizeInput("id", 
                   "My input", 
                   choices = choices,
                   multiple = TRUE,
                   options = list(placeholder = "All choices")
                   )
    )

server <- function(input, output) {

    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When I click on input choices are in this order.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tScm.png

After I start typing "ch", the order of choices is not the same as first picture.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5ofy.png

How to make it so that are choices always in the same order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the behaviour you see is intentional. `selectize.js` (the underlying `JavaScript` library for the `selectInput`) uses [sifter.js](https://github.com/brianreavis/sifter.js) (yet another `JavaScript` library responsible for the search behaviour).

The default setting of `sifter` is to rank the search results according to their best score (where matches in the beginning of a string are scored better than in the middle of the string). Thus, you see that the order is "mixed" up and elements which have a match in the beginning are scored higher and are thus ranked at a higher position.

Luckily, you can override this behaviour with a bit of `JavaScript`. The order in which results are returned can be controlled by a `sortField` property in the settings of  `selectize.js`. By default this equals to `$order` and looking into the [documentation of selectize.js](https://selectize.dev/docs/usage#datasearching) you can see that if there is no explicit `$score` field, results will be sorted **first** according to the `$score` and **then** according to the fields specified in the `sortField` property.

Thus, all we need is to explicitly **add** a `$score` field to `scoreField` **after** `$order` such that results are first sorted according to the intrinsic order and **then** to the score.

The last piece of the puzzle is to determine **where** we can call this custom `JavaScript` b/c for obvious reasons the input element must be already existing before trying to change its settings.

The easiest place I found is to wait for `shiny` to signal that an input element was bound.

To make a long story short, here's the code which assures that the search results are displayed in order:

```r
library(shiny)

choices <- c("First choice", "Second choice", "Choice third", "Fourth choice", 
             "Choice fifth")

js <- HTML("
   $(document).on('shiny:bound', function(evt) {
      if (evt.target.id == 'id') {
         evt.target.selectize.settings.sortField = [{field: '$order'}, {field: '$score'}];
      }
   });
"
   
)

ui <- fluidPage(
   singleton(tags$head(tags$script(js))),
   selectizeInput("id", 
                  "My input", 
                  choices = choices,
                  multiple = TRUE,
                  options = list(placeholder = "All choices")
   )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```